# Android - Issue with Fragment's SavedInstance

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I've checked the document for a change and a possible fix, but now I'm getting activity ComponentInfo error with the new code that is provided by the link you've given. Edited code below.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class TabMainActivity extends Activity {

    ActionBar.Tab Tab1, Tab2, Tab3;
    FragmentTab1 fragmentTab1 = new FragmentTab1();
    FragmentTab2 fragmentTab2 = new FragmentTab2();
    FragmentTab3 fragmentTab3 = new FragmentTab3();

    ArrayList<ListData> dataArray;
    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<DATA> data = new ArrayList<DATA>();
    private static String url = "http://80.240.142.93/nokta/casestudy.json";
    private static final String TAG_VIDEO = "videos";
    private static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String TAG_THUMB = "thumbnail";
    private static final String TAG_LINK = "video_url";
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> videosList;
    Bundle bund = new Bundle();
    private Intent intent;
    private JSONArray listArray;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        bund.putInt("love", 5);
        fragmentTab1.setArguments(bund);

        setContentView(R.layout.tabmainactivity);


        videosList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        if (isNetworkAvailable()){
            new JSONParse().execute();
        }else{
            showMessage("There is no internet connection");
        }   

        android.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        //ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragmentTab1);
        //ft.addToBackStack(null);
        //ft.commit();


        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        // Hide Actionbar Icon
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

        // Hide Actionbar Title
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        // Create Actionbar Tabs
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);


        Tab1 = actionBar.newTab().setText("TAB1").setTabListener(new TabListener<FragmentTab1>(this,"tab1",FragmentTab1.class));
        actionBar.addTab(Tab1);
        Tab2 = actionBar.newTab().setText("TAB2").setTabListener(new TabListener<FragmentTab2>(this,"tab2",FragmentTab2.class));
        actionBar.addTab(Tab2);
        Tab3 = actionBar.newTab().setText("TAB3").setTabListener(new TabListener<FragmentTab3>(this,"tab3",FragmentTab3.class));
        actionBar.addTab(Tab3);


        //ListView listV = fragmentTab1.getListView();

    }
    private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
           @Override
             protected void onPreExecute() {
                 super.onPreExecute();

           }
           @Override
             protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
             JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
             // Getting JSON from URL
                 JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONfromURL(url);
                 return json;

            }
            @Override
              protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
              try {
                 listArray = json.getJSONArray(TAG_VIDEO);
                 {
                     prepareData(json);


                 }

             } catch (JSONException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
             }
           }
              }

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
              = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }
    private void showMessage(String txt){
        Toast.makeText(this, txt, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    private void prepareData(JSONObject json){

        try {

        listArray = json.getJSONArray(TAG_VIDEO);
        dataArray = new ArrayList<ListData>();
        for (int i = 0; i < listArray.length(); i++){
        // tmp hashmap for single contact
        HashMap<String, String> video = new HashMap<String, String>();

        JSONObject c = listArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String jpeg_s = c.getString(TAG_THUMB);
        String title_s = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
        String video_s = c.getString(TAG_LINK);

        video.put(TAG_THUMB, jpeg_s);
        video.put(TAG_TITLE, title_s);
        video.put(TAG_LINK, video_s);

        videosList.add(video);

        try {
            URL newurl = new URL(jpeg_s);
            Bitmap mIcon_val;
            mIcon_val = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(newurl.openConnection().getInputStream());
            ListData prepare_data = new ListData();
            prepare_data.setImage(mIcon_val);
            prepare_data.setName(title_s);
            dataArray.add(prepare_data);
            Log.e("BitMap", mIcon_val.toString());



        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
        //android.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        //android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        //ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragmentTab1);
        //ft.addToBackStack(null);
        //ft.commit();
        ListView lw = fragmentTab1.getListView();
        lw.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this, dataArray));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        /*
        listView.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this, dataArray));
        Log.e("LW", listView.getItemAtPosition(1).toString());*/


        Log.e("returnJSON", videosList.toString());
        }


}
```

**TabListener.java**

```
public class TabListener<T extends Fragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener {


    private Fragment mFragment;
    private final Activity mActivity;
    private final String mTag;
    private final Class<T> mClass;

    public TabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mTag = tag;
        mClass = clz;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String backStateName = mFragment.getTag();
        if (mFragment == null) {
            // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
            mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
        } else {
            // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
            ft.attach(mFragment);
        }   
        Log.e("BAKSTAE", backStateName);

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (mFragment != null) {
            // Detach the fragment, because another one is being attached
            ft.detach(mFragment);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Anyone sees the problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are replacing the Fragment when you switch tabs, and that is telling Android that you don't need the previous fragment any more. Thus when you switch back to it, the data it had is gone.

The docs here have a good example of how to implement your TabListener:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs

In their example, they delay instantiating the Fragment instance (rather that creating all the Fragments in field initializers like you are doing). Then they call `ft.add` if the fragment is new, and `ft.attach` if it is not. Also, when the tab is unselected, they call `ft.detach`.

Comment: If you post the stack from the new exception, I'll try to figure it out. Be sure to post the entire stacks (there may be three or four in a row), and also indicate which line in your code crashed.

Answer (score 0):

try the following code

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle state)  {
     if (mMyView == null) {
         mMyView = new MyView(getActivity());
     } else {
         ((ViewGroup) mMyView.getParent()).removeView(mMyView);
     }

     return mPuzzleView; 
}
```